# Extract strings from HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have following  element:

```
<div class="column4">
        Unlimited Subscription<br/> Discount for Monthly <br/> Total Amount
    </div>
```

How can I extract three strings as three different elements with using Beautiful Soup only. String conversion and regexps can not be used:

Expected output:

```
Unlimited Subscription
Discount for Monthly 
Total Amount
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the individual strings, you could get the `children` of the `div` element and filter them by their type.

```
>>> bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> div = bs.find(attrs={"class":"column4"})
>>> [c.strip() for c in div.children if type(c) is bs4.element.NavigableString]
['Unlimited Subscription', 'Discount for Monthly', 'Total Amount']
```

Or shorter, using `div.stripped_strings` (or just `div.strings` if you don't want to `strip`):

```
>>> list(div.stripped_strings)
['Unlimited Subscription', 'Discount for Monthly', 'Total Amount']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped. I have to study harder not to ask such boaring questions)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the output exactly the way you have shown above, then you can comply something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_elem ="""
<div class="column4">
    Unlimited Subscription<br/> Discount for Monthly <br/> Total Amount
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_elem, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select(".column4"):
    for data in item.select("br"):data.replace_with("\n")
    print(item.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
Unlimited Subscription
Discount for Monthly 
Total Amount
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = """<div class="column4">
        Unlimited Subscription<br/> Discount for Monthly <br/> Total Amount
    </div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
soup.find("div").text.strip()
```

Comment: This is not the right way to do it since a html page may contain more than one `<div>` tag.

Comment: Without seeing the whole HTML code you can't answer this question then. Even in the up voted answer, the author has checked for attributes, which can repeat in many `<div>` tags.

Comment: yeah I understand that but if you see @tobias_k's answer he has used `class` attribute to find the exact match. Since `class` attribute is `unique` with tags it's the correct one. The point i'm trying to tell is even both of the intentions are to find the tag `div` how you use the logic to find ***strict*** match matters.